# Алгоритм увеличения изображения, содержащего градиент

Tags: delphi, изображения, графика

Стоит задача: увеличить изображение 100х100 с четырмя каналами, (красный, зелёный, синий, альфа-канал; содержит сильно размытое пятно), до размера 2500х2500, и вывести на заранее подготовленный графический контекст устройства. Фактически кисть, наподобии кистей в графическом редакторе Adobe Photoshop. Проблема состоит как раз в увеличении (ресайзе). Вот исходное изображение (или кисть; показываю только альфа канал, остальное не принципиально):
[image]
Нарисовано стадартной кистью Photoshop.
А вот, что получается после увеличения моим алгоритмом (ещё раз: не обращайте внимания на цвет: он устанавливается рандомом). Я использовал [ленийное интерполирование](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).
[image]
Вы тоже видите эти шероховатости? Так вот: вся проблема в них. Эти шерховатости находятся в альфа-канале, т.к. цвет у всей кисти однородный. Из-за них, при рисовании линии кистью, образуется страшная грязь. Чтобы понять природу этих неровностей, я решил нарисовать в Photoshop'е полоску шириной 1 пикс., представляющую собой плавный градиент от белого к синему, а потом снова к белому. Далее я увеличил по ширине каждую полоску сначала своим алгоритмом, потом в Photoshop'е: [alt text http://plasmon.rghost.ru/38526229/image.png](http://plasmon.rghost.ru/38526229/image.png)
[alt text http://rghost.ru/38526272/image.png](http://rghost.ru/38526272/image.png)
На первом рисунке опять видно неровности. 
Вот почему, по моему мнению, возникают неровности:[alt text http://rghost.ru/38526320/image.png](http://rghost.ru/38526320/image.png)
Здесь по оси x - номер пикселя, y - цвет. Синие точки - исходные, красные - аппроксимированнные линейной интерполяцией. Синий график показывают идеальную интерполяцию сплайнами, но она слишком долго выполняется на компьтере. Так вот, видите ломаный чёрный график линейной интерполяци? Вот эти самые углы ломаной, мне кажется, образуют такие шероховатости.

В Photoshop'е в настройках стоит интерполяция "Bicubic (best for smooth gradients)", но "Linear" и "Bicubic" в Photoshop'е дают одинаковый с моим алгоритмом результат. Так что можно считать, что "Bicubic (best for smooth gradients)" в Photoshop'е изображение сначала увеличивается линейной интерполяцией а потом применяется банальный фильтр размытия.

---

Итак. Все фильтры размытия которые я нашёл в интернете работают крайне медленно (в т.ч. мой). Скорее всего, Photoshop использует графический ускоритель. Но возможно ли как-нибудь реализовать мою задачу только  с помощью CPU? И чтобы работало максимум секунду. Жду ваших предложений.

---

```
//горизонтальная интерполяция между исходными пикселами
for y:=1 to setedbrush.h_orig do
  for x := 1 to setedbrush.w_orig-1 do
    begin
      x_0:=round(x*k);
      x_x:=x_0+1;
      x_1:=round((x+1)*k);
      y_y:=round(y*k);

      while(x_x<>x_1) do
        begin
          cl:=round((temp[x_1,y_y].r-temp[x_0,y_y].r)/(x_1-x_0))+temp[x_0,y_y].r;
          temp[x_x,y_y].r:=cl;

          cl:=round((temp[x_1,y_y].g-temp[x_0,y_y].g)/(x_1-x_0))+temp[x_0,y_y].g;
          temp[x_x,y_y].g:=cl;

          cl:=round((temp[x_1,y_y].b-temp[x_0,y_y].b)/(x_1-x_0))+temp[x_0,y_y].b;
          temp[x_x,y_y].b:=cl;

          cl:=round((temp[x_1,y_y].a-temp[x_0,y_y].a)/(x_1-x_0))+temp[x_0,y_y].a;
          temp[x_x,y_y].a:=cl;

          inc(x_0);
          inc(x_x);
        end;
    end;
```

Здесь x_0 - крайний известный левый пиксел, соответственно x_1 - правый; x_x - расчитываемый пиксел, y_y - текущая строчка. Формула на основании подобия прямоугольных треугольников.

---

Результат уже лучше, чем прежде. Но при рисовании линии  - грязь. Чтож, придётся сглаживать...  Хотя, может быть, дело в картинке. 
[alt text http://rghost.ru/38553575/image.png](http://rghost.ru/38553575/image.png)

Comment: Или без графического ускорителя не обойтись?

Comment: [http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/photoshop/][1]

[1]:  http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/photoshop/

Comment: Если известно, что изображение - размытое пятно, то может следует использовать это? И применять алгоритм радиально.

Comment: Нет. Это в данном случае.

Comment: @sercxjo, И последний вопрос: уточните пожалуйста ваш ответ: "Кстати можно преобразовать формулы, чтобы заменить деление на умножение и вывести операцию деления за внутренний цикл, будет чуть по-быстрее.

Comment: покажите последний вариант картинки, интересно что у вас получилось

Comment: @sercxjo, Благодарю

Comment: Что-то у меня сомнения по поводу изображенного на графике...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы предполагаете почему они возникают, а вы постройте реальный график изменения яркости вдоль одной какой-нибудь линии.

Cледующий пиксел рассчитывается через предыдущий, так будет накапливаться ошибка. Попробуйте считать по формуле относительно крайних точек, понятно что так ещё одно умножение потребуется, но будет точнее.
Сначала проверьте лучше ли станет интерполяция, если считать по формуле:

```
round((temp[x_1,y_y].a-temp[x_0,y_y].a)*(x_x-x_0)/(x_1-x_0)) + temp[x_0,y_y].a
```

и x_0 во внутреннем цикле **не менять**

Comment: cl:=round((temp[x_1,y_y].r-temp[x_0,y_y].r)/(x_1-x_0))+temp[x_0,y_y].r;

Comment: т.е. только по одной координате растягиваете?
какого типа переменные?

Comment: Сначала каждый элемент x,y исходной матрицы копируется на  элемент x*k,y*k расчитываемой матрицы. Расчитываемая матрица, после этого, выглядит как поле, усеянное точками. Потом между каждой вертикальной и горизонтальной парой точек рисуются ещё точки линейным интерполированием. В данном мной случае интерполирование ведётся горизонтально для красного цвета, где x_0 - первый известный элемент, x_1 - второй, а cl - пиксел между ними. После всего вышеперечисленного, на рассчитываемой матрице образуется как-бы решётка, клетки которой нужно заполнить. Дальше ход действий, я  думаю, вам понятен.

Comment: k - коэффициент ресайза, k > 1

Comment: Что-то я в формуле не вижу координату рассчитываемого пиксела.
cl и temp целочисленные?

Comment: Вот отрывок кода. (в вопросе)

Comment: Понял, следующий пиксел рассчитывается через предыдущий, так будет накапливаться ошибка. Попробуйте считать по формуле относительно крайних точек, понятно что так ещё одно умножение потребуется, но будет точнее. Кстати можно преобразовать формулы, чтобы заменить деление на умножение и вывести операцию деления за внутренний цикл, будет чуть по-быстрее.

Comment: Может и не будет, надо пробовать. Сначала проверьте лучше ли станет интерполяция, если считать по формуле 

round((temp[x_1,y_y].a-temp[x_0,y_y].a)*(x_x-x_0)/(x_1-x_0))+temp[x_0,y_y].a

и x_0 во внутреннем цикле не менять